# WordPress php ajax POST execution 405 Not Allowed after 120 seconds

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

My php code is executing an ajax POST which takes a while to complete but after 2 mins the request fails with 405 Not Allowed. Have specified a high timeout value in ajax. When I specify a value lower than 120 seconds I do see a timeout error.

below is the code being executed

```
$.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo site_url(); ?>/service.php", //the page containing php script
    timeout: 300000,
    type: "POST", //request type
    data: {data1: data1_str, data2: data2_str,  },
    success:function(result){
        // do something
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if(textStatus==="timeout") {  
            alert("Call has timed out " +  textStatus); //Handle the timeout
        } else {
            alert("A different error was returned - " + textStatus + " -- errorThrown - " +  errorThrown); 
        }
    }
});
```

Any ideas on what could be the fix?
Its hosted on Wordpress on Bluehost.

Comment: Checked your server's logs for errors? Pretty hard for us to tell you the issue based upon the snippet you posted

Comment: If it's timing out, the error is almost certainly on `/service.php`. What all is that file doing?

Comment: It is making an api call to a third party. Their call can take upto 3 mins to return data. When their call returns in less than 2 minutes it works fine but if it takes longer I get the error

Comment: I don't anything in the server logs. Looking at error_log in the public_html folder

Comment: @Xhynk The service.php does very minimal work. 
   `$data = json_decode(" SOME JSON DATA STRING", true);`
    `$url="MY_API_URL";`
    `$ch = curl_init( $url );`
    `$payload = json_encode( $data );`
    `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );`
   `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));`
   `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );`
   `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300); `
   `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);`
   `$result = curl_exec($ch);`
   `curl_close($ch);`